# Installing a cocoa pod fails

Tags: ios, cocoapods

It is probably stupid but I get the following error
Unable to find a target named `JustCall`, did find `GPUImage` and `GPUImageFramework`.
Podfile is ---
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'JustCall' do
 pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
end

[image: My Project is clearly correct.]

Answer (score 0):

I moved my pod file from the top list to the bottom ( near the Products folder ) and it mysteriously started to work... I guess some bug is lurking there.